# What does xxx is not defined mean in Python? ( Try to count digits and letters)

Tags: python

I am trying to make a function to detect how many digits,letter,spaces, and others for a string. Do you know what's wrong with my code? 
thanks!

```
def count(x):
    length = len(x)
    digit = 0
    letters = 0
    space = 0
    other = 0
    for i in x:
        if x[i].isalpha():
            letters += 1
        elif x[i].isdigit():
            digit += 1
        elif x[i].isspace():
            space += 1
        else:
            other += 1
    return number,word,space,other
```

it showed this error:

```
>>> count(sdfjalfkjaslfkjs1211)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    count(sdfjalfkjaslfkjs1211)
NameError: name 'sdfjalfkjaslfkjs1211' is not defined
```

if I put count('sdfjalfkjaslfkjs1211'), it gets this error:

```
>>> count('sdfjalfkjaslfkjs1211')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    count('sdfjalfkjaslfkjs1211')
  File "C:/Python34/1.py", line 8, in count
    if x[i].isalpha():
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have  problems apart from  not passing a string as an argument:

You are iterating over the elements and trying to index at the same time:

`number,word` don't exist in your code.  `if x[i].isalpha():` `i` is a string not an `int`, you index strings with ints not other strings.

This will work:

```
def count(x):
    digit = 0
    letters = 0
    space = 0
    other = 0
    for ele in x:
        if ele.isalpha():
            letters += 1
        elif ele.isdigit():
            digit += 1
        elif ele.isspace():
            space += 1
        else:
            other += 1
    return digit, x, space, other, letters
```

If you wanted to index, you could use `for i in range(length):`.

```
In [6]: count("sdfjalfkjaslfkjs1211")
Out[6]: ('sdfjalfkjaslfkjs1211', 0, 0, 4, 16)
```

Comment: thanks for your help! I don't know I could just use for aaa in bbb and find each one.

Comment: no worries, you are accessing each element as you loop over  your input string `x` so you just need to calling your string methods directly on each.

Answer (score 4):

It thinks `sdfjalfkjaslfkjs1211` is a variable name. If you want it to be a string, put it in quotes.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the python compiler can understand what `sdfjalfkjaslfkjs1211` means..

You need to define is somewhere or put in quotes if u want it as a string.